# Can we dynamically pass value to an argument for Spring bean definition?

Tags: java, spring

I want to read value for an argument in Spring bean definition from a property file. Is it possible ?

Example : The value for **persistanceUnit** arg, in below bean definition I need to read from property file or some way configurable.

```
<bean id="profileDao" class="com.sample.dao.kundera.GenericKunderaDaoImpl">
              <constructor-arg name="persistanceUnit" type="java.lang.String" value="cds_test_pu"/>
              <constructor-arg name="persistentClass" type="java.lang.Class" value="com.sample.model.cds.Profile"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If spring has picked up your property file you can use an expression to reference the property:

```
<bean id="profileDao" class="com.sample.dao.kundera.GenericKunderaDaoImpl">
              <constructor-arg name="persistanceUnit" type="java.lang.String" value="${cds_test_pu}"/>
              <constructor-arg name="persistentClass" type="java.lang.Class" value="com.sample.model.cds.Profile"/>
</bean>
```

Spring boot can discover certain configuration files by convention. In the old xml configuration days you would reference your config file using a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations" value="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
    </bean>
```

Spring boot has a lot of functionality regarding externalization of your configuration - have a look here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config

Answer (score 0):

To add on

1. You can also use Spring expression language SPEL to resolve the value dynamically in bean definition in xml.
2. You can also register a BeanDefinition to Spring  BeanDefinitionRegistry in a programmatic way on application start-up.